# How to invalidate a Cloudfront distribution using the AWS Python CDK?

Tags: python, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

We have a static site which is hosted in S3 and I'm trying to create a stack which will automate uploading the files and invalidate the Cloudfront distribution.

I can upload the files but can't see any way to create the invalidation.

I can get the distribution like this:

```py
distribution = aws_cloudfront.Distribution.from_distribution_attributes(
    self,
    id="ImportedDistribution",
    domain_name="https://hgfdh.cloudfront.net",
    distribution_id="hgfdh",
)
```

but can't see how to create the invalidation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no construct for invalidation in Python CDK. Here is an example in boto3.

```
import boto3

def invalidate_cloudfront_distribution(distribution_id, paths):
   client = boto3.client('cloudfront')

   response = client.create_invalidation(
       DistributionId=distribution_id,
       InvalidationBatch={
           'Paths': {
               'Quantity': len(paths),
               'Items': paths
           },
           'CallerReference': str(hash(tuple(paths)))
       }
   )

return response
```

You could maybe implement this as a Lambda function instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as part of the BucketDeployment:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3_deployment/README.html#cloudfront-invalidation

```py
aws_s3_deployment.BucketDeployment(
    self,
    "DeployWithInvalidation",
    sources=[aws_s3_deployment.Source.asset("./build/fdsf")],
    destination_bucket=website_bucket,
    distribution=distribution,
    distribution_paths=["/*"],
)
```